# How to use DropDownList.SelectedIndex from datasource?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Wizard for registration. 
In step 1, I have few controls that goes into table dbo.Emp. In this step1, I have couple of DropDownList that is binded from code-behind from different table called dbo.Emptype.

However, while inserting the form to table dbo.Emp, I am getting following error-

```
Insert Error:Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

I do not know for which control it is telling it for.

But there is a statement here-

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpType",DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", DropDownList3.SelectedIndex);
```

I want the INT values that is associated with items in EmpType to be inserted into the table.
DropDownList1 is binded to the table called Dbo.EmpType (TypeID (PK- AutoIncrement)| Type)
So, when a user drops down that control and select value, I need DataValueField (i.e TypeID) to get inserted into the table.

What do I do?

This is my bind class.

```
public void dropdowntype()
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT Type, TypeID FROM EmpType", myConn);
            myConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader3 = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Set up the data binding.
            Emp_type.DataSource = myReader3;
            Emp_type.DataTextField = "Type";
            Emp_type.DataValueField = "TypeID";
            Emp_type.DataBind();



 //Close the connection.
            myConn.Close();
            myReader3.Close();

        }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
            {
                dropdownDept();
                dropdowntype();
                dropdownskills();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the data value feild from your dropdown then use this statement

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpType",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID",DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
```

You are currently selecting the index of the dropdown.

Comment: SelectedValue selects the item.. I do not need that..
I need Index associated with the item..

Comment: dear SelectedItem dislplays the Selected item. Show me the code where you have bind your dropdown

Comment: what is your DropDownList1.TextFeild and DropDownList1.ValueFeild ?

Comment: As you can see "TypeID" is assigned to DataValueField.. I want that value to get into the FK key called "Emp_type" in dbo.Emp

Comment: @Girish I saw your post, in order to get TypeID you have to use Emp_type.SelectedValue.

Comment: @Waqar.. I used this way cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpType",Emp_type.SelectedIndex); and it worked..

Comment: @Girish but SelectedIndex returns index of the dropdown not the value. index starts from 0 to .... n. SelectedValue returns the value which you have bind from your database in this line  Emp_type.DataValueField = "TypeID";

Comment: It says "Insert Error:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TypeID' to data type int." when I used .DataValueFiel